# PyQt: how to receive keyboard events in a subclassed QWidget?

Tags: python, qt, events, pyqt, subclass

Maybe this is been asked many times, but i can't find a solution.

I have a dialog:

```
class PostDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog() #code from designer!!
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.plainTextEdit = ContentEditor()
```

This dialog has a QPlainTextEdit from the designer.

I need to override keyPress and keyRelease of that QPlainTextEdit.

So i have subclassed it:

```
class ContentEditor(QtGui.QPlainTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print "do something"
```

but ContentEditor.keyPressEvent is never called! Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [installEventFilter](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for this purpose:

This would look like:

```
class PostDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog() #code from designer!!
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.plainTextEdit.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            # do some stuff ...
            return True # means stop event propagation
        else:
            return QtGui.QDialog.eventFilter(self, event)
```

Comment: this worked, thanks. there are some syntax errors in your code, but that is the answer. anyway, i don't understand how do that with subclassing yet..

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to accomplish is better done by ***promoting*** in Qt Designer the QPlainTextEdit widget to your subclass ContentEditor.
[Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) 

In the "Promoted Widgets" Dialog:
"Promote class name": ContentEditor
"Header file": your_python_module_name.h

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to call method `setFocusPolicy`of QWidget to receive a KeyPress Event.
From API docs of [QWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) for the method *keyPressEvent*:

```
This event handler, for event event, can be reimplemented in a subclass 
to receive key press events for the widget. A widget must call setFocusPolicy() 
to accept focus initially and have focus in order to receive a key press event.
```

Comment: You also need to change focus policy of other widgets around it. For example, you can set mywdiget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus) (in PyQt) to ensure mywidget won't ever have key press functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably just need to swap the following two lines:

```
self.ui.setupUi(self)
self.ui.plainTextEdit = ContentEditor()
```

If you write it like this:

```
self.ui.plainTextEdit = ContentEditor()
self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

you make sure your custom widget gets bound before the UI gets setup. Otherwise you're just replacing a reference to an already initialised object.

Comment: this doesn't work because in the setupUi self.ui.plainTextEdit is initialized with a QPlainTextEdit object.